# What is the purpose of using `-m`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems to me `python -m myscript` and `python   myscript` do the same thing: running a script.

What is the purpose of using `-m`? Thanks.

Comment: One is invoked as a module.

Comment: Have you tried [reading the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)?

Comment: `python -m myscript` is *sometimes* similar to `python myscript.py`. Notice the `.py`. Also, `-m` allows you to run a module in a sub-package, which is not always viable when running as a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases, especially for very small projects, `python script.py` and `python -m script` will be pretty much the same.

The biggest difference is when your module lives in a package and has relative imports. If you have a script that import something like `from .module import some_name`, you will most likely get a `ModuleNotFoundError` when you run it with `python package/scripy.py`. On the other hand, `python -m package.script` will produce whatever output you expected.

Answer (score 3):

You can load modules and invoke them as script. The exact file name or path is not needed. Example:

```
python -mjson.tool myfile.json
```

This will print a formatted version of `myfile.json`, and it loads the module `json.tool` for this. Python searches for this module automatically. You don't need to know the exact path.